# Why isn't auditd logging file deletes?

Tags: logging

I have `auditd` installed on 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 to track down some unexpected deletes ([nice discussion of auditd](http://security.blogoverflow.com/tag/auditd/)). This is my rule (tagging deletes with the `deletes` keyword):

```
-a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S unlink -S rmdir -k deletes
```

`auditctl -l` shows that it's configured:

```
LIST_RULES: exit,always arch=3221225534 (0xc000003e) key=deletes syscall=rmdir,unlink
```

This works perfectly:

```
# mkdir xyx
# rmdir xyz
# ausearch -k deletes|grep 'xyz'
type=PATH msg=audit(1406147794.737:1880): item=1 name="xyz" inode=12386307 dev=08:04 mode=040755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00
```

but this does not:

```
# touch xyx
# rm xyx
# ausearch -k deletes|grep 'xyz'
```

I can see that all sorts of other deletes are logged. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same issue, just found the solution. You will need to use `unlinkat` as the system call tracing:

```
-a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S unlink -S rmdir -S unlinkat
```

because `rm` isn't using `unlink`. Thanks [theillien](https://superuser.com/users/201668/theillien) for the [answer posted here on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/968574/596513):

Answer (score 0):

If this

```
 -a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S unlink -S rmdir -k deletes
```

is your command where do you tell it to log `rm`? I would assume it would log `rmdir` and not log `rm` at all (as shown by your 2 examples it seems the case).

Looking at the auditd lay-out I would assume you need something like:

```
-a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S unlink -S rm -S rmdir -k delete
```

Comment: It doesn't connect to the `rm` binary, it's connecting to the `unlink` system call, which is what `rm` uses, along with anything else that deletes a file, such as the PHP `unlink` function. There isn't an `rm` system call.